# How to remove a module using Anaconda in Python

Tags: python, package, anaconda

I have a package called 'Prody' which is installed under anaconda directories:

```
$ python 
Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2014, 15:36:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> import prody
>>> prody.__file__
'//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ProDy-1.5.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/prody/__init__.pyc'
```

I'd like to remove that file with this command but failed:

```
$ conda remove prody
Error: no packages found to remove from environment: //anaconda
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Package names can differ from the name you import; does it also show up as `prody` in `conda freeze` (or the equivalent)?

Comment: `$ //anaconda/bin/pip freeze` gave `ProDy==1.5.1`. I tried `conda remove ProDy` also of no avail.

Comment: Why not "/.../anaconda/bin/pip uninstall ProDy"?

Comment: I had tensorflow installed through conda install, and tensorflow-gpu through pip install, when I try 'conda remove -n tensorflow', I got "CondaValueError: Value error: no package names supplied,". But after I did 'pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu', then  'conda remove -n tensorflow' succeeded.

Answer (score 6):

You can remove packages installed with pip using `pip uninstall`.

Answer (score 3):

Did you install Prody via `pip`? Then I don't think that `conda remove` can remove it. AFAIK, conda manages only conda packages.